# Identical items in a queue

Tags: vb.net

Would it be possible to tell whether the two items in a queue are identical? My queue is used to store error message and in some cases, two of the same error messages can be added to the queue, but i dont want to display them twice.
And then i could dequeue one of the error messages.

Comment: You could use `.Peek()`. Although "identical" could be problematic.

Comment: 1 choice I see is calling contains before adding the new message.

Comment: instead of error messages store error *codes* and it becomes very easy to avoid dupes